# Como obter o produto escalar de dois vetores em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, matemática

Em python, se tenho dois vetores, consigo obter o produto escalar usando `numpy`. Segue exemplo:

```py
x=np.array([2,4,6])                                                                                                                                                                
y=np.array([1,3,5])                                                                                                                                                                
np.dot(x,y)
```

Retorna:

```
44
```

Estou procurando uma função equivalente no Javascript. Encontrei uma chamada [math.do](https://mathjs.org/docs/reference/functions/dot.html). Mas, infelizmente, não estou conseguindo usar essa função. Eu tentei:

```js
let a=[2,4,6];
let b=[1,3,5];
console.log(math.dot(a,b))
```

Que retorna o erro:

```
ReferenceError: math is not defined
```

Eu tentei escrever `Math` como maiúsculo:

```js
let a=[2,4,6];
let b=[1,3,5];
console.log(Math.dot(a,b))
```

Mas retornou o erro:

```
TypeError: Math.dot is not a function
```

O que estou fazendo errado aqui? Como posso obter um produto escalar no Javascript?

Comment: Tente reproduzir o erro aqui, por favor? Uma sugestão é utilizar o snippet de códigos.

Comment: Editei a pergunta para incluir o snippet

Comment: Como você fez para incluir a biblioteca? Utilizou algum `<script src>` com alguma CDN, por exemplo? Ou está rodando no Node.js?

Comment: Estou rodando no node.js

Comment: Você instalou a biblioteca utilizando `npm`? Está utilizando o `require`? Ainda faltam detalhes em sua pergunta.

Comment: Não estou usando o `require`. Desculpe, sou um completo newbie em Javascript. Esse módulo `Math` funciona no navegador, mas para usar no node eu preciso importar? Como faço para importar?

Comment: Não precisa pedir desculpas!! :) Você consegue acessar o "módulo" [`Math`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math) porque ele é um objeto global _built-in_ do JavaScript. Já a biblioteca em questão (`mathjs`) ao qual você se referiu não é "nativa", então você precisa importá-la de alguma maneira. Só estou tentando entender o que você fez (porque atualmente a pergunta precisa de mais detalhes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se você está no Node.js<sup>[[Comentário]](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/491300/como-obter-o-produto-escalar-de-dois-vetores-em-javascript#comment913710_491300)</sup>, deve instalar a biblioteca através de um [gerenciador de pacotes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Understanding_client-side_tools/Package_management). No Node.js, os gerenciadores de pacote mais comuns são o `npm` (que já vem instalado por padrão com o Node.js) e Yarn, que pode ser instalado à parte.

Para instalar uma biblioteca utilizando Node.js, a partir da pasta raiz do seu projeto, execute o comando:

```
npm install <nome da biblioteca>
```

No seu caso, deverá fazer `npm install mathjs`, conforme a [documentação](https://mathjs.org/download.html#install) aponta. Você pode verificar a página da biblioteca `mathjs` no site do npm [aqui](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mathjs).

Uma vez que você tenha instalado a biblioteca, pode utilizar o `require` para importá-la:

```
const math = require('mathjs');

let a = [2,4,6];
let b = [1,3,5];
console.log(math.dot(a, b)); //=> 44
```

Note que ao contrário de CDNs (utilizadas comumente nos *browsers* para a importação de bibliotecas), no Node.js os objetos não são expostos globalmente. Assim, você deve importar a biblioteca que quer utilizar explicitamente.

O `require` do Node.js segue o padrão CommonJS. Existe também o ECMAScript modules, que pode ser utilizado como "sintaxe" alternativa ao CommonJS em versões mais recentes do Node.js.

A título de curiosidade, se estiver em versão do Node.js que suporte, pode utilizar a sintaxe de ECMAScript modules:

```js
import * as math from 'mathjs';

let a = [2,4,6];
let b = [1,3,5];
console.log(math.dot(a, b)); //=> 44
```

---

Saiba mais sobre o [CommonJS](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/modules.html) no contexto do Node.js. E sobre o [ECMAScript modules](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/esm.html).

Answer (score 2):

O `math.js` funciona perfeito e retorna o mesmo resultado:

```js
let a=[2,4,6];
let b=[1,3,5];
console.log(math.dot(a,b))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/9.0.0/math.js"></script>
```

Pela mensagem não adicionou a lib corretamente, pode fazer o download ou usar o link para um cdn na internet e adicionar na tag `<script>`. Veja aqui alguns links de cdn que pode usar: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/mathjs

Se for usar no node ou um script no server, precisa instalar o package, as instruções estão também na página no Math: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mathjs

Pode instalar com o `npm`, usando o comando: `npm install mathjs`

Comment: Minha dificuldade é na parte da importação mesmo. Eu estava usando o módulo `Math` sem importar, mas agora descobri que ele é built-in e por isso estava conseguindo usar. Esse outro módulo eu preciso importar. Só preciso entender o processo de importação agora. A linha `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/9.0.0/math.js"></script>` está em um HTML ou no próprio arquivo `js`? Estou rodando o `js` no Node

Comment: sim, a tag `script` deve estar na mesma página onde está o código javascript que vai usar o Math :)

Comment: e como faço para fazer a importação usando apenas o arquivo `js` no node?

Comment: ah calma lá, vai usar isso no node? então não adianta instalar na página, vai precisar instalar o package. Aqui na página do Math tem as instruções: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mathjs   Para ajudar vou colocar na resposta